# IOS/Objective-C: Syntax error with NSURL URLWithString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am trying to implement code from SO answer with a slight modification but having problems:

Here is the original code:

```
     dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
            NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/%@.jpg",
[[myJson objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"movieId"]]]];
```

Here is my code:

```
  NSString *picname = item.pic;
     NSString *picURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.~com/itempics/%@",item.pic];
     NSURL *urlPicUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:picURL];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{ 
                NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:picURL]]; //THROWS ERROR
```

My code is throwing error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'
```

Would appreciate it if anyone can spot what is causing this error:

Comment: Seems to be crashing on tilde sign in the given url http://www.~com/itempics. Please put your valid url.

Comment: Please check  NSString *picURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.~com/itempics/%@",item.pic]; it is returning nil. Please pass valid url

Comment: Clearly not a syntax error. Syntax errors are caught at compile time, this is runtime. Set a breakpoint on exceptions (plenty of questions and answers about this around) and start debugging.

Comment: Both picURL and urlPicUrl log ok to console.  When I substitute google's logo for my pic url, get same error:  https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png instead of "http://www.~com/itempics/%@",item.pic

Comment: Its working fine at my end. May be you are getting crash some where else.

Comment: @gnahser.  You were right.  I set exceptions breakpoint and it turns out error was not where it was breaking in console but in another line altogether.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I guess `item.pic` is null.
And `picname` is never used in your code.

Did you miss something to paste in your code?